# HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy are containing both a class of the name HibernateGrailsPlugin

Tags: grails

I get `HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy` are containing both a class of the name `HibernateGrailsPlugin` when run a grails app.anyone can help me.

ps:(my reputation is no  enough，so the pic is not):

```
eb-service\work\plugins\hibernate-1.1.1\HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy are contain
ing both a class of the name HibernateGrailsPlugin.
 @ line 27, column 1.
   class HibernateGrailsPlugin {
   ^

1 error
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(Compil
ationUnit.java:813)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.j
ava:464)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.j
ava:443)
        at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure6_closure49.doCall(_PluginDepe
ndencies_groovy:413)
        at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure6_closure49.doCall(_PluginDepe
ndencies_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:2
74)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure6.doCall(_PluginDependencies_g
roovy:412)
Error loading plugin manager: startup failed, D:\guni-web-service\..\guni-model\
plugins\hibernate-1.1\HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy: 27: Invalid duplicate class
definition of class HibernateGrailsPlugin : The sources D:\guni-web-service\..\g
uni-model\plugins\hibernate-1.1\HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy and D:\guni-web-ser
vice\work\plugins\hibernate-1.1.1\HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy are containing bo
th a class of the name HibernateGrailsPlugin.
 @ line 27, column 1.
   class HibernateGrailsPlugin {
   ^

1 error
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `hibernate-1.1.1`? Which version of Grails?

Comment: I run it on grails 1.1.1.I think I know how to solve.There are the same two class in my Project.Let me try.

Comment: You know that Grails is in 2.3, right? :-)